# Postgresql session's custom parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, session

To log table data changes in the PostgreSQL DB I created triggers on table ON UPDATE and ON INSERT, however besides having what is changed I want to know who changed it, but the site code is using one "DB user" to connect to DB, which I can get via CURRENT_USER variable. How can I attach some parameter("site user" name) to a DB session, so later I can get it in DB in triggers function. On the site site I'm using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: There is no built-in support for session variables in PostgreSQL, but you can emulate it (in theory - i did not used it before) using a temporary table and 2 functions (getter & setter).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry that I'm answering my question, but just found another solution
using customized options http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-custom.html

In postgresql.conf add

if version >= 9.2

```
site.user = NULL
```

if version <= 9.1

```
custom_variable_classes = 'site'
site.user = NULL
```

Then in the scope of transaction

```
SELECT SET_CONFIG('site.user', 'user name', true); 
...
SELECT INTO site_user CURRENT_SETTING('site.user');
```

Comment: Interesting one, this may can work - however, be aware that they are reserved for extension module settings, so if you choose a prefix, you cannot use that extension (if there is one) without warnings, or probable misbehavior.

Comment: No need to initialise your variables in the .conf; you can define them on the fly. And if you want to scope the variable to your session instead of your transaction, just pass `false` to `set_config()` instead of `true`.

Comment: good catch, there is no necessity to initialize in .conf, I guess in the old version only the line "custom_variable_classes = 'site'" is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with PostgreSQL natively.  One option might be to modify your database connection code (client-side) to set that information in the database session every time you connect:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE active_user (site_user VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO active_user (site_user) VALUES (?);
```

Then later in your triggers:

```
...
DECLARE site_user VARCHAR;
...
   SELECT INTO site_user site_user FROM active_user
...
```